# What does group do in the aes parameter of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can someone please help explain what the group parameter does in ggplot2? I'm looking at a line of code that looks as follows:

```
ggplot(summarized.current.data, aes(x = GROUP_ID, y= Endpoint.Value, color = GROUP_ID, group = GROUP_ID))
```

On the bottom of my chart I correctly get group_id,  on the y-axis I get the endpoint value. It correctly colors them by group. But what does the "group = GROUP_ID" do? The charts do come out different but I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Did you check `?group`. There are examples in the help document for you to play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the detail by using

?aes_group_order

in short,group can draw many lines group by the factor levels