# Why do we use group = group in ggplot2 plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why do we use `group = group` within ggplot plot?

Please advise.

e.g:

```
ggplot(state, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group))
```

What does the group = group statement actually do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664664/what-does-group-do-in-the-aes-parameter-of-ggplot2

Comment: It doesn't answer my question...

Comment: @Prof.DanielPetterson Yes it does! Did you do any research/reading yourself before posting here? That's what users expect around here on SO. If unsure please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). As to your question, see `?aes_group_order` and the examples therein.

Comment: This question has been placed completely out of context. There should be minimal reproducible examples. We don't always put `group = group` that is specific to your example. If you follow the advice of Maurits Evers and combine that with the advice neilfws gave you, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example that you give is for plotting maps, usually starting from a shapefile. In that case the data contains a column named `group` which is used by `geom_polygon` to ensure that boundaries and shapes are connected correctly. If the column were named something else, *e.g.* `xxx`, then you'd use `group = xxx`.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577160/bizarre-polygons-from-a-shapefile) demonstrate what happens when grouping is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The `group` option is an *aesthetic* as `color` or `size` and is set to an object. So as previously mentioned, you data here should contains a variable called `group` that's why you have `group = group`.

You can dig into more detail reading the book of Hadley Wickham, http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html.